# how to print wchar_t array to file in 64 bit windows

Tags: c, winapi, widechar, windows64

I want to output some wchar_t array filled from some windows api into a file opened with fopen:

```
wchar_t content[256];
SomeWindowsAPI(content, 256);
FILE *file;
file=fopen( "C:\\log","a+");
fputs(content , file); //????
```

However, fputs expects a const char* array. Is there some other C api to write to a file pipe that expects wide array characters?

Comment: @KerrekSB: add a link to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t33ya8ky%28v=vs.71%29.aspx and make that an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For printing a null-terminated sequence, the wide analogue of `fputs` is [`fputws`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fputws.html):

```
int fputws(const wchar_t *restrict ws, FILE *restrict stream);
```

As an alternative, you can write the raw data in your wide string with `fwrite`:

```
wchar_t str[] = L"Hello World";
FILE * fp = /* ... */;

fwrite(str, sizeof(wchar_t), wcslen(str), fp);
```